# Expresso Store and inventory limit message

Tags: expresso-store

I ended up selecting an item that had only 1 item in inventory.  I selected 2, but it automatically selected 1 because of the inventory level. Is there any way to have displayed a note explaining that? Something like available X in stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is, see Store's total_stock tag - https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#total_stock

```
{if total_stock > 0} 
    {total_stock} in Stock 
{if:else} 
    Out of Stock 
{/if}
```

Comment: How to get this to work with `modifier_options`? It shows sum of all product options not X stock amount per product option.

Comment: Check the docs page I gave you, there are variables available for stock levels for individual SKU's - direct link https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#store_product_stock_level